# Query to check if grouped rows have value 1

Tags: mysql, sql

Lets say i have the following table "products"

```
id |title|images_missing
13 |shoes| 0
14 |shirt| 0
```

and another table "variations"

```
id|product_id|color|size|image
1 |        13|red  |M   |0
2 |        13|red  |XL  |1
3 |        13|green|M   |0
3 |        13|green|S   |0
```

where each product can have multiple variations (variation is defined by color+size).

I need a query to check for every color if there is at least one variation that has an image and if there is at least one color without an image (in this case green) the product row in the first table needs to get the value 1 for missing images.

Can you help me with this?

**EDIT:**

Just to make things a litte more clear, my goal is to update the products table and to set the field "images_missing" to either 1 ( = at least one color has no images at all ) or to 0 ( = each color has at least one variation with image = 1)

This means:

- get all variations with product_id = 13
- check if at least one variation with color=red has image = 1
- check if at least one variation with color=green has image = 1

=>

- if no variation with color=red has image = 1, update product with id 13, set missing_images = 1

OR

- if no variation with color=green has image = 1, update product with id 13, set missing_images = 1

Comment: Specify the expected result as well. And show us your current query attempt.

Comment: I don't completely follow your requirements.  By showing us your expected output, you can clarify your question.

Comment: Is the image field of "variations" is bool or int?

Comment: variations.image is actually int

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be this?

```
select p.id,p.title,count(1) images_missing
from products p
inner join 
(select product_id,color,sum(image) 
from variations
group by product_id,color
having sum(image)=0) as v 
on p.id = v.product_id
group by p.id,p.title
```

Answer (score 1):

You can count the number of colors with images and the number overall.  This provides a single expression for determining if any colors are missing images:

```
select p.*,
       coalesce(v.images_missing, 0) as images_missing
from products p left join
     (select product_id, 1 as images_missing
      from variations v
      group by product_id
      having count(distinct color) <> count(distinct case when image = 1 then color end)
     ) v
     on p.id = v.product_id;
```

Comment: This unfortunately doesn't seem to work yet.. What is "product_missing"?
Seems like you might have mixed something up there..

Comment: @cn313 . . . What does "doesn't seem to work" mean?  That is very vague.

Comment: it says Unknown column 'v.v' in 'field list'